# Vb.Net - Invoke in Task

Tags: vb.net

so basically I want my application to run a method that is quite cpu intensive and therewhile it should constantly display status information on a different form. To prevent this status form from freezing, I thought it would be a good idea to outsource the code into a new thread.

First I tried to use basic threadding and invoking the richtextbox control which should display status messages. - Problem is - I need to know when the Thread is finished to carry on with my main thread. Obviously I cannot simply run a loop in my main thread that keeps checking if the process is finished, cause that would make my GUI freeze, too.

So I did a little bit research and found out about Tasks.
That's how it looks:

```
Dim z as new complexProcessClass
Dim taskA = task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() z.start())
taskA.Wait()
If taskA.IsCompleted Then
   MsgBox("finished")
End If
```

And whenever the process reports a status I use this:

```
Public Class complexProcessClass
  dim statusWindow as statusForm

  Public Sub start()
    statusWindow = new statusForm
    'complex code here
    reportStatus("bla")
    'complex code here
    reportStatus("blabla")
    'complex code here
  End Sub

  Private Delegate Sub UpdateTextHandler(ByVal Text As String)
  Private Sub reportStatus(Byval s as String)
    If z.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
      Try
        z.RichTextBox1.Invoke(New UpdateTextHandler(AddressOf xform.RichTextBox1.AppendText), s)
       Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
       End Try

     Else
        z.RichTextBox1.AppendText(s)
     End If
  End Sub
```

But it just keeps freezing on the invoke call - no error message - nothing?!

Can anybody tell me the correct way to do this? - and please no backgroundworker solution ;)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.aspx) class. This [post](http://garylima.blogspot.com/2009/09/backgroundworker.html) should get you started.

Another approach is to create delegates and call the thread asynchronously and implement an update function to catch when the work is done.

1. **Create a class** with the work code as a function
2. **At the top** of the class create/add Delegate Function Handler
3. **Inside of your form** add a handler to the new class with a call to your class method.
4. **Create a callbackhandler method** to receive the status of the thread performing the export functionality.Have the callbackhandler call an update ui function that checks if the thread is running from the UI or is another thread. (Me.InvokeRequired checks this)
5. **Inside of the Form btn click event** call the method using
   the targetHandler call.

The below code is what the form code would look like.

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private targetHandler As ClassName.Handler = AddressOf objNewClass.somework
```

Private callbackHandler As AsyncCallback _
                               = AddressOf MyCallbackMethod


Sub MyCallbackMethod(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    '*** this code fires at completion of each asynchronous method call
    Try

        Dim retval As Boolean = targetHandler.EndInvoke(ar)
        If retval = True Then
            Console.Write(retval)
        End If
        UpdateUI("Task complete")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim msg As String
        msg = "Error: " & ex.Message
        UpdateUI(msg)

    End Try
End Sub

Sub UpdateUI(ByVal statusMessage As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim handler As New UpdateUIHandler(AddressOf UpdateUI_Impl)
        Dim args() As Object = {statusMessage}
        Me.BeginInvoke(handler, args)

    Else
        UpdateUI_Impl(statusMessage)
    End If
End Sub

Delegate Sub UpdateUIHandler(ByVal statusMessage As String)

Sub UpdateUI_Impl(ByVal statusMessage As String)
    Me.sbMain.Panels("Status").Text = statusMessage
End Sub
'Call to your worker thread
Private Sub btn_Click() Handles Button1.Click 
 Dim result As IAsyncResult =targetHandler.BeginInvoke(callbackHandler,Nothing) 
End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0):

You have a deadlock situation where `taskA.Wait()` is blocking the UI thread, and the `Invoke()` call inside `taskA` is waiting for the UI thread to finish what it's doing. Which is waiting until it's done waiting. Which is never.

I'm not entirely sure, but try this:

```
Dim taskA = task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() z.start()).ConfigureAwait(False)
```